# Slow Startup of Ubuntu

Tags: startup

When I run the `systemd-analyze blame` command the following enabled services show up

```
     52.231s plymouth-quit-wait.service
     15.176s snapd.service
     15.051s dev-sda5.device
     12.565s networkd-dispatcher.service
     12.202s systemd-journal-flush.service
     11.897s gpu-manager.service
     10.950s ModemManager.service
     10.698s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      9.294s udisks2.service
      8.115s dev-loop1.device
      6.849s accounts-daemon.service
      6.706s NetworkManager.service
      5.915s dev-loop11.device
      5.579s dev-loop18.device
      5.480s dev-loop2.device
      5.299s dev-loop12.device
      5.253s systemd-resolved.service
      5.156s dev-loop19.device
      5.029s dev-loop14.device
      5.020s dev-loop16.device
      4.924s dev-loop9.device
      4.575s thermald.service
      4.571s grub-common.service
      4.447s apport.service
      4.341s dev-loop7.device
      3.968s systemd-logind.service
      3.594s avahi-daemon.service
      3.531s bluetooth.service
      3.526s wpa_supplicant.service
      3.489s fwupd.service
      3.366s dev-loop8.device
      2.919s rsyslog.service
      2.760s dev-loop10.device
      2.731s dev-loop6.device
      2.656s dev-loop4.device
      2.644s dev-loop5.device
      2.390s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-90E0\x2d8818.service
      2.371s apparmor.service
      2.255s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      2.108s polkit.service
      1.943s dev-loop3.device
      1.870s dev-loop13.device
      1.764s dev-loop0.device
      1.727s systemd-udevd.service
      1.641s dev-loop15.device
      1.405s dev-loop17.device
      1.391s systemd-sysctl.service
      1.298s gdm.service
      1.094s upower.service
       874ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-406.mount
       838ms snap-core18-1066.mount
       837ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1198.mount
       836ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-254.mount
       832ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
       821ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-71.mount
       821ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-296.mount
       820ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-100.mount
       783ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       755ms snap-libreoffice-139.mount
       754ms snap-core18-1074.mount
       747ms systemd-modules-load.service
       673ms snap-vlc-1049.mount
       644ms pppd-dns.service
       639ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1313.mount
       633ms snap-chromium-821.mount
       583ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       565ms snap-core-7270.mount
       552ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       532ms systemd-sysusers.service
       525ms keyboard-setup.service
       497ms systemd-rfkill.service
       482ms systemd-journald.service
       466ms switcheroo-control.service
       423ms snapd.seeded.service
       383ms plymouth-start.service
       347ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       332ms networking.service
       323ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-67.mount
       314ms colord.service
       308ms snap-core-7396.mount
       296ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       289ms openvpn.service
       278ms swapfile.swap
       206ms snap-gimp-189.mount
       182ms ifupdown-pre.service
       181ms snap-chromium-817.mount
       180ms nvidia-persistenced.service
       172ms dns-clean.service
       169ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       169ms dev-mqueue.mount
       166ms dev-hugepages.mount
       163ms boot-efi.mount
       163ms plymouth-read-write.service
       162ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-77.mount
       162ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-61.mount
       154ms rtkit-daemon.service
       149ms snap-hw\x2dprobe-337.mount
       137ms systemd-random-seed.service
       132ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       125ms ufw.service
       121ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       119ms setvtrgb.service
       107ms kerneloops.service
        99ms console-setup.service
        97ms bolt.service
        91ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        65ms user@1000.service
        11ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
         9ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         1ms sys-kernel-config.mount
         1ms snapd.socket
```

---

I ran the `sudo systemctl disable plymouth-quit-wait.service` command but plymouth is still enabled.

```
 1min 6.773s plymouth-quit-wait.service
 1min 1.002s apt-daily.service
     15.251s snapd.service
     14.660s dev-sda5.device
     11.631s gpu-manager.service
     10.466s networkd-dispatcher.service
      9.981s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      9.371s systemd-journal-flush.service
      9.164s ModemManager.service
      8.504s dev-loop15.device
      8.164s udisks2.service
      7.776s dev-loop7.device
      7.656s accounts-daemon.service
      7.052s NetworkManager.service
      5.700s grub-common.service
      5.653s apport.service
      5.627s systemd-resolved.service
      5.596s dev-loop8.device
      5.507s dev-loop1.device
      5.081s dev-loop13.device
      4.958s dev-loop10.device
      4.859s dev-loop16.device
      4.817s dev-loop3.device
      4.731s dev-loop2.device
      4.708s dev-loop11.device
      4.427s dev-loop17.device
      4.271s avahi-daemon.service
      4.208s systemd-logind.service
      4.208s thermald.service
      4.204s bluetooth.service
      4.204s rsyslog.service
      4.126s dev-loop0.device
      4.102s dev-loop6.device
      3.918s networking.service
      3.745s dev-loop14.device
      3.720s wpa_supplicant.service
      3.542s dev-loop5.device
      3.523s plymouth-start.service
      3.460s dev-loop9.device
      3.444s dev-loop12.device
      3.358s systemd-udevd.service
      3.292s dev-loop4.device
      2.982s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-90E0\x2d8818.service
      2.756s apparmor.service
      1.931s packagekit.service
      1.898s polkit.service
      1.695s upower.service
      1.168s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
      1.127s gdm.service
      1.102s plymouth-read-write.service
      1.004s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       990ms snap-core18-1066.mount
       862ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
       833ms systemd-sysusers.service
       687ms snapd.seeded.service
       673ms snap-gimp-189.mount
       631ms systemd-modules-load.service
       626ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       597ms systemd-rfkill.service
       579ms keyboard-setup.service
       567ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-67.mount
       561ms snap-core18-1074.mount
       545ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-71.mount
       544ms snap-core-7270.mount
       543ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-296.mount
       542ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-77.mount
       519ms pppd-dns.service
       508ms colord.service
       502ms switcheroo-control.service
       489ms systemd-sysctl.service
       482ms systemd-journald.service
       459ms systemd-localed.service
       447ms snap-vlc-1049.mount
       445ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1198.mount
       444ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-406.mount
       437ms swapfile.swap
       425ms systemd-hostnamed.service
       407ms snap-core-7396.mount
       406ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-254.mount
       399ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       326ms snap-libreoffice-139.mount
       321ms kerneloops.service
       281ms ifupdown-pre.service
       281ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       275ms boot-efi.mount
       243ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1313.mount
       239ms dns-clean.service
       236ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-100.mount
       194ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-61.mount
       190ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       175ms console-setup.service
       160ms ufw.service
       149ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       138ms setvtrgb.service
       133ms systemd-random-seed.service
       121ms snap-hw\x2dprobe-337.mount
       116ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       100ms kmod-static-nodes.service
        95ms dev-mqueue.mount
        84ms openvpn.service
        76ms rtkit-daemon.service
        68ms user@1000.service
        39ms snapd.socket
        11ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
        10ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         4ms nvidia-persistenced.service
         3ms dev-hugepages.mount
         3ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
         2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         1ms sys-kernel-config.mount
```

How do I disable it once and for all.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166486/how-to-decrease-the-boot-time

Answer (score 0):

First problematic service is the `plymouth`.

> Plymouth is the application which provides the graphical "splash"
>   screen when booting and shutting down an Ubuntu system.

You can safely disable this service by issuing this command :

```
sudo systemctl disable plymouth-quit-wait.service
```

After that, reboot Your PC and run `systemd-analyze blame` again to see the difference. You can disable other services depending on whether or not You actually need them.