# Slow login time on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with clean install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, login

This is my first foray into Linux so I am not really sure what to do/where to look.

As the title says, after logging in to my user account, the system will hang on a black screen for approximately 30 seconds before finally getting to the desktop.
I am assuming this is way to long, since I can get into windows in approximately 10 seconds from hitting the power button.

I am using a dual boot setup on an Acer Aspire A515-54g laptop on an SSD.
The install is clean, Ubuntu has been installed and the automatic updates applied. Nothing else.

`systemd-analyze blame` shows:

```
7.129s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      3.351s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      2.298s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-61.mount
      2.297s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-406.mount
      2.293s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-100.mount
      2.280s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1313.mount
      2.276s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-67.mount
      2.241s snap-core-7270.mount
      2.237s snap-core18-1066.mount
      2.191s snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-81.mount
      2.171s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-296.mount
      2.006s systemd-logind.service
      1.944s NetworkManager.service
      1.189s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
       743ms console-setup.service
       716ms fwupd.service
       443ms keyboard-setup.service
       305ms dev-nvme0n1p5.device
       141ms dev-loop2.device
       130ms snapd.service
       110ms dev-loop3.device
       103ms udisks2.service
       102ms networkd-dispatcher.service
```

`systemd-analyze` output:

```
Startup finished in 2.722s (firmware) + 1.049s (loader) + 1.803s (kernel) + 24.247s (userspace) = 29.821s
```

Comment: I don’t find 18.04 to be particularly fast to boot with gnome. I much prefer LXQt. Have a look here “https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166486/how-to-decrease-the-boot-time?rq=1“ Could be systemd is waiting for network connections.

Comment: Try "systemd-analyze critical-chain". That will show you which components are impacting total boot time. The components with the largest +nn.nn numbers are the ones worth looking at. My Acer Aspire E1-572 returns about 13.6 seconds in response to a simple systemd-analyze. That's a less capable laptop than yours but it is running Arch and LXQt. "systemd-analyze plot > file.svg gives a complete graphical representation.