# Extremely slow Kubuntu Boot (18.04 LTS)

Tags: boot, kubuntu

My Kubuntu 18.04 (LTS) takes about 3 minutes to boot. It is about 6 months old atm.

Following are the relevant details :

```
uname -a
Linux konsole 5.0.0-31-generic #33~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 10:20:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
systemd-analyze 
Startup finished in 5.754s (kernel) + 46.078s (userspace) = 51.833s
graphical.target reached after 46.059s in userspace
```

(Selecting the first few)

```
systemd-analyze blame
         15.969s systemd-journal-flush.service
         13.596s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
         13.000s networkd-dispatcher.service
         12.798s dev-sda1.device
          8.445s gpu-manager.service
          7.320s udisks2.service
          6.598s ssh.service
          5.433s NetworkManager.service
          5.351s ModemManager.service
          4.917s systemd-udevd.service
          4.525s vboxdrv.service
          4.520s apparmor.service
          4.164s grub-common.service
          3.576s accounts-daemon.service
          3.110s thermald.service
          3.109s bluetooth.service
          3.107s lm-sensors.service
          2.491s wpa_supplicant.service
          2.335s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          1.901s systemd-rfkill.service
          1.862s systemd-logind.service
          1.709s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-199d5cb3\x2d2d16\x2d4f3f\x2d8af8\x2d99c53ad33b9f.service
          1.634s avahi-daemon.service
          1.441s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
          1.286s packagekit.service
          1.271s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          1.168s systemd-modules-load.service
          1.157s binfmt-support.service
          1.045s keyboard-setup.service
```

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @30.321s
└─multi-user.target @30.321s
  └─networkd-dispatcher.service @20.286s +10.034s
    └─basic.target @17.615s
      └─sockets.target @17.615s
        └─avahi-daemon.socket @17.615s
          └─sysinit.target @17.523s
            └─apparmor.service @14.592s +2.930s
              └─local-fs.target @14.590s
                └─home.mount @14.347s +242ms
                  └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-199d5cb3\x2d2d16\x2d4f3f\x2d8af8\x2d99c53ad33b9f.service @12.804s +1.478s
                    └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-199d5cb3\x2d2d16\x2d4f3f\x2d8af8\x2d99c53ad33b9f.device @12.803s
```

Comment: Related: [How to decrease the boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166486/how-to-decrease-the-boot-time)

Comment: Hey @Raffa, I tried that and it only improved it by a 20 second margin. It still takes more than2 minutes to boot.

Comment: Currently, postfix slows eveyrhing down

Comment: Do you need postfix? Is this machine a mail server? If yes, troubleshoot postfix to see what is slowing down the service and fix it. If no, disable the postfix service or uninstall postfix all together.

Comment: Yep, figured I had to disable postfix right after I commented, boot-time is still around 30-40 s. Something called Networkd-dispatcher service is slowing it down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few services can be disabled to reduce the boot-up time with no effect on the desktop environment functionality in **most cases**:

---

**Firstly:**

**POSTFIX** appears in your post. If your machine is not a mail server and you do not use POSTFIX you can disable the `postfix.service` by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo systemctl disable postfix.service
```

Or you can uninstall POSTFIX all together by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt remove postfix
```

---

**Secondly:**

**`NetworkManager-wait-online.service`** can be disabled by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

Please refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1166492/968501) for more explanation.

---

**Thirdly:**

**Two services** that rely on the functionality of `NetworkManager-wait-online.service` are **`networkd-dispatcher.service`** and **`systemd-networkd.service`**. These can be disabled as well by running the following commends in the terminal:

```
sudo systemctl disable networkd-dispatcher.service
```

And:

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-networkd.service
```

These two services are used strictly for **systemd**'s connectivity purposes and will not affect the connectivity of the desktop environment after login.

Comment: Thanks. This helps a little, boot time is now around the 1.20 mins mark. Will post the critical chain once I get home.