# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS slow boot

Tags: boot

I recently upgraded from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. The booting takes very long and while opening applications for the first time after boot takes a while. This was not the case in 18.04.
 Here is the output of systemd-analyze blame.

> 40.177s plymouth-quit-wait.service
>   13.821s networkd-dispatcher.service
>   12.331s dev-sda7.device
>   11.938s snapd.service
>   10.914s udisks2.service
>    9.756s apport-autoreport.service
>    9.003s accounts-daemon.service
>    6.878s ModemManager.service
>    5.834s dev-loop9.device
>    5.799s dev-loop15.device
>    5.622s avahi-daemon.service
>    5.620s bluetooth.service
>    5.533s iio-sensor-proxy.service
>    5.476s dev-loop4.device
>    5.452s dev-loop7.device
>    5.441s dev-loop8.device
>    5.368s NetworkManager.service
>    5.357s polkit.service
>    5.245s dev-loop16.device
>    5.164s dev-loop14.device
>    5.126s dev-loop0.device
>    5.125s dev-loop2.device
>    5.122s dev-loop13.device

Here is the output for systemd-analyze critical-chain

> graphical.target @1min 6.301s
>   └─multi-user.target @1min 6.301s
>     └─networkd-dispatcher.service @20.621s +13.821s
>       └─basic.target @19.895s
>         └─sockets.target @19.895s
>           └─snapd.socket @19.894s +646us
>             └─sysinit.target @19.762s
>               └─systemd-timesyncd.service @19.415s +346ms
>                 └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @17.088s +2.324s
>                   └─local-fs.target @17.084s
>                     └─run-snapd-ns-canonical\x2dlivepatch.mnt.mount @31.721s
>                       └─run-snapd-ns.mount @29.157s
>                         └─local-fs-pre.target @5.700s
>                           └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @4.740s +960ms
>                             └─systemd-sysusers.service @3.947s +792ms
>                               └─systemd-remount-fs.service @3.604s +136ms
>                                 └─systemd-journald.socket @3.532s
>                                   └─-.mount @3.515s
>                                     └─system.slice @3.515s
>                                       └─-.slice @3.515s

Comment: Disabling `networkd-dispatcher.service` might help. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1182196/590085). Also snap packages might be causing the problem (all those dev-loop<number>.device), using `.deb` might help. Also [see](https://askubuntu.com/a/1284332/590085)