# Slow Boot after installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, 14.04, 20.04, usb

After installing fresh LTS release of Ubuntu 20.04 with USB bootable stick, I'm facing slow boot of my laptop compared to old LTS version i.e. Ubuntu 14.04. What can be done to improve boot speed of laptop?
Laptop description- Dell Inspiron15- 3000 series
4GB RAM, 500GB HDD, Intel Core i3 5005U CPU@2GHzx4, OS 64bit
(No Windows installed, only single Ubuntu OS)
systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 6.047s (firmware) + 5.504s (loader) + 3.985s (kernel) + 44.256s (userspace) = 59.793s
graphical.target reached after 44.174s in userspace

systemd-analyze blame
22.532s plymouth-quit-wait.service
22.532s plymouth-quit-wait.service
16.554s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.533s dev-sda2.device
10.164s systemd-journal-flush.service
10.149s networkd-dispatcher.service
9.503s snapd.service
6.821s accounts-daemon.service
6.380s udisks2.service
6.341s fwupd.service
5.423s NetworkManager.service
4.503s polkit.service
3.821s dev-loop2.device
3.810s dev-loop6.device
3.792s dev-loop3.device
3.785s dev-loop1.device
3.746s dev-loop5.device
3.742s dev-loop4.device
3.725s dev-loop7.device
3.707s dev-loop0.device
3.631s avahi-daemon.service
3.629s bluetooth.service
2.965s gpu-manager.service
2.926s ModemManager.service

systemd-analyze critical-chain
graphical.target @44.174s
└─multi-user.target @44.174s
└─kerneloops.service @38.115s +166ms
└─network-online.target @38.096s
└─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @21.541s +16.554s
└─NetworkManager.service @16.114s +5.423s
└─dbus.service @16.111s
└─basic.target @15.936s
└─sockets.target @15.936s
└─snapd.socket @15.934s +1ms
└─sysinit.target @15.854s
└─snapd.apparmor.service @15.432s +421ms
└─apparmor.service @14.237s +1.193s
└─local-fs.target @14.236s
└─boot-efi.mount @14.191s +44ms
└─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1D00\x2d6320.ser>
└─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1D00\x2d6320.device @14.057s
Please suggest how to speed the boot.

Comment: See `man systemd-analyze` for the tools you need.

Comment: Other related questions & answers. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster  But if you really want faster booting invest in a SSD.

Comment: Disabling `networkd-dispatcher.service` might help. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1182196/590085). Also snap packages might be causing the problem (all those dev-loop<number>.device), using `.deb` might help. Also [see](https://askubuntu.com/a/1284332/590085)