# Ubuntu 20.04 Slow openapplication and slow boot

Tags: boot

**Hi Guys as my question and these are my output**

45.554s plymouth-quit-wait.service
26.346s dev-sda2.device
24.183s snapd.service
19.839s networkd-dispatcher.service
17.115s systemd-journal-flush.service
15.089s dev-loop0.device
15.086s dev-loop7.device
15.082s dev-loop1.device
15.074s dev-loop9.device
15.072s udisks2.service
14.923s dev-loop13.device
14.911s dev-loop12.device
14.866s dev-loop11.device
14.691s dev-loop8.device
14.680s dev-loop10.device
14.667s dev-loop15.device
14.549s dev-loop17.device
14.522s dev-loop14.device
14.499s dev-loop16.device
14.253s dev-loop18.device
13.772s accounts-daemon.service
12.877s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
11.940s dev-loop3.device
lines 1-23

****I have added output from `inxi -F`**

```
System:
  Host: wnkk-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500 Kernel: 5.8.0-63-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20202 v: Lenovo IdeaPad Z500 
  serial: <superuser/root required> 
  Mobo: LENOVO model: INVALID v: 00000000INVALID 
  serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: LENOVO v: 71CN22WW(V1.05) 
  date: 09/14/2012 
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT1 charge: 30.4 Wh condition: 30.4/N/A Wh 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i5-3210M bits: 64 type: MT MCP 
  L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
  Speed: 1345 MHz min/max: 1200/3100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1317 2: 1353 
  3: 1382 4: 1373 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] driver: nouveau v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.9 
  driver: fbdev,intel,modesetting,nouveau,nvidia,vesa 
  resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2) 
  v: 4.2 Mesa 20.2.6 
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 7 Series/C216 Family High Definition Audio 
  driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA GF108 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.8.0-63-generic 
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet driver: r8169 
  IF: enp2s0 state: down mac: b8:88:e3:98:63:33 
  Device-2: Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230 driver: iwlwifi 
  IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: 60:36:dd:57:b0:c5 
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 24.86 GiB (2.7%) 
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB 
  size: 931.51 GiB 
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 915.40 GiB used: 24.85 GiB (2.7%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 43.0 C mobo: N/A gpu: nouveau temp: 49 C 
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:
  Processes: 245 Uptime: 39m Memory: 5.66 GiB used: 1.59 GiB (28.0%) 
  Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.38
```

Comment: Disabling `NetworkManager-wait-online.service`  and `networkd-dispatcher.service` might help. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1182196/590085)