# Slow boot time in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, 22.04, services

I am new to Ubuntu.Just wanted to know if there is any way to reduce my boot time any further(I am using HDD).Currently it takes 1 min 31 seconds.

```
systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 8.061s (kernel) + 1min 23.131s (userspace) = 1min 31.192s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 23.055s in userspace
```

Following are the details:

```
systemd-analyze blame
42.635s plymouth-quit-wait.service
23.877s systemd-journal-flush.service
22.750s networkd-dispatcher.service
20.374s snapd.service
19.755s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
14.015s udisks2.service
13.017s apache2.service
12.189s dev-sda2.device
11.926s ModemManager.service
11.647s cups.service
10.216s dev-loop15.device
 9.726s dev-loop5.device
 9.033s gdm.service
 8.706s accounts-daemon.service
 7.684s NetworkManager.service
 7.063s snapd.seeded.service
 5.838s dev-loop3.device
 5.807s dev-loop14.device
 5.784s dev-loop11.device
 5.781s dev-loop16.device
 5.761s dev-loop10.device
5.522s power-profiles-daemon.service
 5.440s polkit.service
 5.150s dev-loop12.device
 5.128s dev-loop13.device
 5.111s dev-loop17.device
 5.072s dev-loop6.device
 4.961s dev-loop9.device
 4.926s dev-loop8.device
 4.878s dev-loop2.device
 4.806s dev-loop0.device
 4.540s avahi-daemon.service
 4.538s bluetooth.service
 4.108s thermald.service
 3.806s switcheroo-control.service
 3.799s systemd-logind.service
 3.775s wpa_supplicant.service
 3.180s dev-loop4.device
 2.733s systemd-resolved.service
 2.705s dev-loop7.device
 2.644s gpu-manager.service
 2.240s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
 2.212s secureboot-db.service
 2.179s rsyslog.service
```

Comment: See "Secondly" and "Thirdly" in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1182196