# Slow boot time Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: boot

Ubuntu 20.04 webserver
Platforms : Webmin/Virtualmin
Hardware: i5-4570 + 8gb ram and 1 SSD

I had installed OpenMediaVault at some point on server and i purged it and removed ssd with the openmedia vault.
I think boot time is affected by this.
Here are some commands from logs:

```
systemd-analyze time
```

Results:

> Startup finished in 5.827s (firmware) + 2.794s (loader) + 3.302s (kernel) + 1min 40.095s (userspace) = 1min 52.019s
> graphical.target reached after 1min 39.551s in userspace

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
#      
# / was on /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-CJuruIAJZ5Q4ZkBVfCqAwkGKk2ZIm32RCgDjKUKm1sYS3TRzwt OQyPyeFc3HBDR0 / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/205cf80c-fb9e-473a-82d6-25329a34e693 /boot ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/26BE-A316 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
# /home was on /dev/ubuntu-vg/lv-0 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-CJuruIAJZ5Q4ZkBVfCqAwkGKk2ZIm32R3790Nfb6JxUmVgpjlx JwhtuwqXnJ9vDS /home ext4 usrquota,grpquota,quota,rw,relatime 0 1
/swap.img none swap sw 0 0
LABEL=myvault /home/myvault ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/sda5 /free ext3 defaults 0 0
```

```
 

sudo blkid -o listdevice
```

```
 

root@ns2:/# sudo blkid -o listdevice fs_type label mount point UUID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sda1 vfat /boot/efi 26BE-A316
/dev/sda2 ext4 /boot 205cf80c-fb9e-473a-82d6-25329a34e693
/dev/sda3 LVM2_member (in use) xSawZN-We9k-jleS-QCAB-nRRB-sAKr-8a3Qnd
/dev/sda5 ext3 /free 53e83fc3-d397-4021-a00e-a4bc4360ba45
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4 / cb9e6bda-3cf2-426c-bb17-e2978292f8aa
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv--0 ext4 /home fd9bce36-259b-4012-960c-d352934d2af1
/dev/loop0 squashfs /snap/core20/1879
/dev/loop1 squashfs /snap/lxd/23991
/dev/loop2 squashfs /snap/core20/1891
/dev/loop3 squashfs /snap/snapd/18933
/dev/loop4 squashfs /snap/lxd/24061
/dev/loop5
```

```
 
systemd-analyze critical-chain
```

```
 
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.


graphical.target @1min 39.551s
└─multi-user.target @1min 39.551s
└─postfix.service @1min 39.548s +1ms
└─postfix@-.service @1min 37.427s +2.120s
└─network-online.target @1min 37.407s
└─systemd-networkd-wait-online.service @1min 32.257s +5.148s
└─systemd-networkd.service @1min 32.196s +59ms
└─network-pre.target @1min 32.195s
└─firewalld.service @1min 31.788s +406ms
└─polkit.service @1min 31.310s +475ms
└─basic.target @1min 31.281s
└─sockets.target @1min 31.281s
└─uuidd.socket @1min 31.281s
└─sysinit.target @1min 31.273s
└─cloud-init-local.service @1min 30.522s +751ms
└─systemd-remount-fs.service @454ms +11ms
└─systemd-journald.socket @439ms
└─system.slice @435ms
└─-.slice @435ms
Weird jump from remount fs service from 454 ms to cloud-init-local.service at 1min30sec
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extremely slow Kubuntu Boot (18.04 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181672/extremely-slow-kubuntu-boot-18-04-lts)

Comment: ... And remove or comment out `LABEL=myvault /home/myvault ext4 defaults 0 0` in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Thank you! That was the culprit. From 2.5minutes of boot to 20 seconds. Kernel was trying to acces that partition and is not on.