# boot time issue

Tags: boot

```
graphical.target @2min 42.292s
└─multi-user.target @2min 42.292s
  └─winbind.service @1min 7.456s +12.614s
    └─network.target @1min 7.454s
      └─NetworkManager.service @56.957s +10.495s
        └─dbus.service @50.005s
          └─basic.target @49.836s
            └─sockets.target @49.836s
              └─snapd.socket @49.832s +3ms
                └─sysinit.target @49.545s
                  └─systemd-timesyncd.service @49.116s +429ms
                    └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @45.573s +3.507s
                      └─systemd-journal-flush.service @4.573s +40.999s
                        └─systemd-journald.service @3.866s +705ms
                          └─syslog.socket @3.811s
                            └─system.slice @3.756s
                              └─-.slice @3.712s
```

please help to get the boot time issue resolved

Comment: Related: [How to decrease the boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166486/how-to-decrease-the-boot-time)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make it clear what you want and what the problem exactly is.

Comment: Just a shot, try: `sudo /usr/bin/NetworkManager --no-daemon` and see if any error messages are displayed. Source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=243403

Comment: What does `ll /tmp | wc -l` show? Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162594/systemd-slow-boot-systemd-tmpfiles-setup

Comment: ll /tmp | wc -l shows 21