# What is slowing down my system?

Tags: boot, performance

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.  It seems like my system is running slower than it should.

When I turn on my laptop, it takes 1-2 minutes to boot.

The problem continues even after booting.  Everything seems to be too slow, including the terminal, file manager and firefox.

`Dell LATITUDE E7440 , intel core-i5 , 8GB RAM`

Please help me review the output of:

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

*https://paste.ubuntu.ir/liyl*

`htop` command :

[image]

Comment: when I bought this laptop ,win 8.1 was installed on this .it was very faster than Ubuntu

Comment: take a look at `htop` or any other real-time system monitoring tool.   You should review to see if there are any processes that are taking a huge percentage of memory, CPU, or disk r/w  -- Report back with an [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1264824/edit) to let us know what you've found.  Please also include in your post the details of your hardware (especially what model CPU and the amount of installed RAM)

Comment: what do you think about changing desktop ? in a Persian forum a person told me change to XFCE .

Comment: No, I would not recommend that you **change** your desktop unless you are very familiar with what exactly that entails.  You could maybe try or install Xubuntu (official Ubuntu flavor with Xfce).  As far as looking at `htop` you should review it when your system is "slow".  This screenshot shows nothing consuming all your resources.  And what about your CPU model and how much RAM do you have exactly? Maybe you are asking too much of your hardware?  "Slow" is not a defined term.  We need you to find some concrete evidence pointing to *some* culprit in your Ubuntu installation

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1166492

Comment: **processor** : Intel® Core™ i5-4310U CPU @ 2.00GHz × 4  --- **memory** : 7.7 GiB . First launch of each app is slow and it takes 54.982s to boot . on this laptop and win 8.1  ,boot takes less than 30s  and launching apps was faster .

Comment: Well your CPU is a 7-year-old low-power laptop chip, so I would not expect it to be very fast to begin with. FYI: Windows 10 is probably using "fast startup" which is a hybrid suspend. That would mean it's not truly booting in 30s.  You should also turn this off if you are dual-booting.  Maybe you should not use GNOME, and use another flavor of Ubuntu like Lubuntu that is not nearly as bloated

Comment: so there is no way to make it faster ?

Comment: We need to first determine the cause of the slowness.  Have you been able to see any deficiencies as you are monitoring your system during the problem behavior?

Comment: I didn't understand . but I monitored using `htop` and tried to open Telegram desktop ,it didn't open but in **CPU usage** _NetworkManager_ go up to 10% ,some processes of Firefox using up to 5% . in **Memory usage** all tasks is for Firefox with 5.1%

Comment: Can you explain more precisely? I'm not good in English .