# slow boot with SSD

Tags: boot, ssd

replaced HDD with SSD because slow boot ,boot is only about 2X faster than HDD!!

25 seconds from pressing the power key to the login screen

`core-i5-4310U 2GHz - 8GB Ram DDR3`

`systemd-analyze blame` using HDD :

https://paste.ubuntu.ir/liyl

`systemd-analyze blame` using SSD :

https://paste.ubuntu.ir/amnx

commands in [how to decrease the boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166486/how-to-decrease-the-boot-time) just decreased time in `systemd-analyze` and boot time with stopwatch has no changes

I removed **snap** ,disabled **NetworkManager-wait-online.service**

using `systemd-analyze` startup takes **7.683s** but but 25s to viewing login page .

Comment: The speed of the ssd is more important than the processor, cpu speed or the amount of ram :P Include `systemd-analyze blame`  into the question please. That will show the units and time needed to load.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decrease the boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166486/how-to-decrease-the-boot-time)

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service
I typically uninstall all snaps and for the few I want install the .deb. In grub I change quiet splash to `noplymouth`, you then see boot process.

Comment: they didn't help!!!