# Boot delay of 30 seconds on kubuntu 22.10

Tags: boot, usb, kubuntu

The last "normal speed" entry in dmesg reads:

```
[    5.108969] hid-generic 0003:154A:0002.0003: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.00 Device [ID Innovations Inc. Input Device] on usb-0000:04:00.3-3.2.1.4/input1
```

The next one:

```
[   34.740815] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
```

Any hint out there what's slowing down the boot process?

Thanks

Comment: Can you check the S.M.A.R.T. information of the related nvme device? You can use the `smartctl` command line or the `gsmartcontrol` GUI tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try `systemd-analyze plot > plot.svg` and open the `svg` file using firefox or something, take a look and see what is taking time.

`systemd-analyze blame` will also show you how much each task took on boot, but it's sorted by time, not sequentially after boot

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer! systemd-analyze blame issued first: 

49.267s NetworkManager-wait-online.service 

Might that process be the culprit? –

Comment: Yes, and you can easily disable that service if  your system isn't a server. See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166486/how-to-decrease-the-boot-time

Comment: I suggest you look at the plot as well, there you can see some services will not start until a certain service is started successfully before them, if you reduce the time these services are waiting, it can have much more impact (for example, a service may be waiting for `systemd-journald.service`, and it is taking too long, then if you flush your journald logs, it may help significantly.)

Comment: The link above worked! Thank you!