# Boot locks up forever waiting until the internet network is connected then it resolved permanently. why?

Tags: boot, internet

HP X360 Envy Ubuntu Ryzen 5
I had long term issue with newer kernels and I had to boot into the older kernel to boot (escape key then advanced, choose older kernel).
However I discovered the escape button got me a detailed boot info and it seemed to be hanging on
"a startup job is running for network name resolution"
then this time I connected the internet as it booted again and it defaulted to the newer kernel and was ok for that and subsequent boots.
is this a snap problem?
Ethernet Network is only available with USB adapter for this model.
For something to make the computer almost unusable (glad I kept the older kernals). what is going on here?

Comment: also I have a vpn installed which is autoconnect, killswitch etc. and when I connected the internet like it seemed to want to, I had to reboot to get through it all.

Comment: You've provided no Ubuntu product details (*are you asking about a Ubuntu Core system? Ubuntu Server? or Ubuntu Desktop?*) nor what release of that *unstated* product?  If it's a LTS release, there are multiple *supported* kernel stack options & you've not given any clue as to which you're asking about, or all? as if you have problems with one stack; why not try another?  (the doco highlights testing a second stack, before you remove your initial stack for a reason).. Are you asking about *edge* kernels? *oem* kernels? *GA*? *HWE*? etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decrease the boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166486/how-to-decrease-the-boot-time)

Comment: ... However, it shouldn't wait "forever" unless you (or a package/script installed by you) changed something.

Comment: I know I did not put all the details in, meaning to later. Ubuntu Linux 5.15.0.91 is the latest and did not boot , it does now. and 5.13.0.35 was the good one I had to manually choose from grub menu. hardware also has a keyboard issue. I will be sticking my NVME drives in a second machine in the next few days.

Comment: 5.15 is a kernel & is far from the *latest* (that is 6.5).  A kernel also isn't very specific, as the 5.15 kernel is the HWE stack for a 2020 release (ie. older release) but also the GA kernel stack for a more recent LTS release. 5.13 is **not** a supported kernel, being from 21.10 which was EOL long ago (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/) being a release from 2021.  I'd suggest trying a *recent* release if your details are accurate; as you're talking about older releases (from 2020 possibly, ie. 20.04 LTS)

Comment: might even have been an nvme ssd problem, I swapped it out to another one that also had this OS installed and problem is gone, even boots to newest kernel, and the touchscreen issue (it disappeared) also went away. only issue now 9for which I might start a new thread) is the touchscreen location does not change the mouse touchpad location in this scrabble game. oh and another problem was Clonezilla backup would abort with gobbledegook on the screen, now works, indicating again an ssd problem. (or not screwed down properly). the update might have helped too, guiverc.